# Newbie wants to know what is a Root administrator password?

Tags: password

I trying to load the driver for the Lexmark printer which was downloaded form their site. I get to a point where Ubuntu 12.04 asks for the root administrator password. I don't recall putting one in upon installation. If I did how can I retrieve it again? BUT if I didn't then what would it be?

Comment: Wha about your user password, do you still remember that one? When installing Ubuntu you are supposed to provide an username and a password. That is your so-called 'root' password.

Comment: Have tried that password on numerous occasions but never seems to accept.

Comment: I was able to change the password. Thanks everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+alt+t

type: sudo passwd root

(set password)

that should do it

(found at : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo )

otherwise..

As administrator it is same as your login password.
My experience is Ubuntu cannot install without you choose a password.
you can google -forgot password ubuntu- to find what to do or watch this youtube movie
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUuJzDlH0w4

Solution is about holding down shift during bootup. My problem was I could not enter boot menu. So, easy as it was, just reinstalled ubuntu to reset password, took half an hour.
A possibility but prob. not the best one.

Good Luck!